# Translate a signature and Seal on a painting (Characters identified: 甲子春畫 醇士)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal, calligraphy

Was given a gift by a friend who had these from an uncle who, it was believed visited China around 1960's.  I have tried to translate the signature and seal using on line tools with little success.  Hoping someone can help.
[image]

Comment: Important: 畫 in 春畫 is a verb, not a noun

Comment: So, it's a painting "Done in Spring", and not a "Painting of Spring"?

Answer (score 1):

It means "(This paint was)painted in spring in Wood Rat Year by 醇士 chún shì "

"甲子Wood Rat" is the 1st combination of the sexagenary cycle of the Chinese zodiac.(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wood_Rat)

According your describe this paint probably finished in 1864 or 1924, since the next Wood Rat year is 1984.

I don't know who is "醇士" . I have googled for this name and found some artist called 彭醇士 péng chún shì (1896～1976) but not sure whether this was painted by him or not.

This might required a professional antique dealer to answer your question.